# Remove rows from one table based on comparison to another

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have two data tables and need to get a list of rows in one that are not in the other. For example, the tables could look like this:

```
Table1:
FN    LN    EMAIL               POBox    CustID
John  Doe   johndoe@here.com    123       9876
Jane  Doe   janedoe@here.com    234       9888
Some  Guy   someguy@here.com    877       8888

Table2:
FN    LN    EMAIL               POBox
John  Doe   johndoe@here.com    123
Some  Guy   someguy@here.com    444
```

I need to get back, from Table1, the row containing Jane Doe (in Table1 but not in Table2) and row containing Some Guy (POBox in Table1 not same as in Table2) using Linq. I know I can loop through the rows of table and spit out the row if I cannot find it in Table2 but don't know how to do it using Linq. Comparison needs to be made using all common fields (FN, LN, EMAIL and POBox).

Comment: What is/are the primary key field(s)?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate because the proposed duplicate requires a custom compound key, which this does not (may not).  For this example, the answer is a much simpler `var result=List1.Except(List2);`

Comment: Thanks Robert. The data are in two data tables and not lists. They also come from two different databases on two different DB servers. However, just the like fields from those tables are stored in the two data tables.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing it, one would be like this.

```
table1.Where(t1=>!table2.Any(t2=>t1.Email == t2.Email))
```

Comment: Thank you AD.Net. If I want to make sure three of the four fields are compared, do I change the "Any(...)" to "Any(t2=>t1.Email == t2.Email && t1.FN == t2.FN && t1.LN == t2.LN)"?

Comment: I had to add "AsEnumerable()" after table1 and table2 to access "Where" and "Any". However, once I type "t1." or "t2." none of the fields FN, LN, EMAIL and POBox are available.

Comment: I really wish some moderators who are too quick either down voting questions or marking them as duplicate spend a few minutes reading the question before exercising their "God" privilege. I googled the question and did not find a suitable answer. Even when I was posting the question here, I went through the suggested ("duplicate") posts before posting my question. For anyone who might run into this "duplicate" issue, here is the link to the solution I got from another forum. http://forums.asp.net/p/2048949/5907333.aspx?p=True&t=635669551632107220